# Regular Expression non-ASCII character

Tags: python, regex

I'm having a bit of trouble with a regular expression in python. The html string is:

> ```
> html = <td style="padding-right:5px;">
> <span class="blackText">Above £ 7.00 = </span>
> </td>
> <td>
> <span class="blackText">
> <p>Free</p>
> </span>
> </td>
> ```

I want to extract the "7.00" and "Free", however the following does not work:

> amount = re.findall(r'Above £ (.*?) =',html)

Python throws up a non-ASCII error for the £ symbol. How would I get around this? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
amount = re.findall(r'Above \xC2 (.*?) =', html)
```

Comment: How did you get `\xC2`? My Python seems to be using `\xa3` for the sterling symbol.

Comment: @chrisaycock - depends on encoding. `\xa3` is html entity. `\xC2` is utf-8. see (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a3/index.htm)

Comment: @JayWalker - OP has experienced error regarding non-ASCII character, so it will be utf-8